# react promise in functional component

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, use-effect, react-functional-component

I have a functional component in which I want to save the data in my inputs form sending them with saveForm method to my java API.

**How can I read the response of this promise** props.saveForm (in order to look for potentials server errors) **in a functional component**? I've read that in these cases it must be used **useEffect** hooks..but If I move my handleSubmitForm() inside useEffect than I can't call it when the onSubmit event is thrown.

Please enlight me.
Thank you for your wisdom.

Code I found in others questions :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const saveForm= async () => {  //!but like this is not fired on the onSubmit event!
      const result = await axios.get(`/api/formpage/${id}`);
      setData(result.data.inputs); 
    };
    fetchInitialData();
}, []);
```

My code right now:

```
const handleSubmitForm= (e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   props.saveForm(newData, props.history);
};


return (
<div>
  <Styles>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}>
        .....
         <input ..... />
         <input ..... />
        .....
    </form>
  </Styles>
</div>
);
```

actions.js:

```
export const saveForm= (newData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
   const res = await axios.post("/api/formexample", newData);
   dispatch({//this dispatch is to clean past errors if now are resolved
   type: GET_ERRORS,
   payload: {},
});
} catch (err) {
   dispatch({
   type: GET_ERRORS,
   payload: err.response.data,
});
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put your `handleSubmitForm` in a `useEffect`. This function is being used in response to a button click, so it's not an effect.

You can make your function `handleSubmitForm` async and do an await.

```
const handleSubmitForm = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const result = await callValidation(data));

   // check your result
};
```

I'm not sure how you are checking your validation, so this is just an example.

Comment: nice that work! just another thing...I'm using redux and redux-thunk so I really would prefer to make these promise in a separate file called action...thing is if I use async /await here then I can't use it another time there to connect with reducers and store and dispatch the result. How should I do in this case?

Comment: Save form and submit form are two different actions. You should probably treat them as such. You can have one action that validates and submits and another that just validates. They can share some code to prevent duplication.