# Is it possible to use values of promises in a functional React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't think this is a duplicate of [react promise in functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586906/react-promise-in-functional-component) since that triggers the promise on an event.  I want to display a value of a promise specifically `SecureStore.isAvailableAsync()` from Expo.

Basically I was wondering if I can do something similar to https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/executing-promises-in-a-react-component with the functional components.

I am thinking of `useEffect` but that requires a void return parameter.

This is what I have attempted so far

```
  const [ secureStorageAvailable, setSecureStorageAvailable ] = React.useState<boolean|null>(null);
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    return () => setSecureStorageAvailable(await SecureStore.isAvailableAsync());
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at your first attempt there are a few things to consider about [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    return () => setSecureStorageAvailable(await SecureStore.isAvailableAsync());
  });
```

- you can't declare `useEffect` function as `async`. you can declare inside or outside and call it in (or like an IIFE as you did);
- returned function will be performed only on unmount component phase;
- not passing a second argument results in your function being execute on every component rerender;

regarding your approach it's perfect valid to call as an IIFE. You could declare the function outside then call it inside or also declare inside then call it:

```
  React.useEffect( () => {
    const updateSecureStorage = async () => {
      setSecureStorageAvailable(await SecureStore.isAvailableAsync());
    };
    updateSecureStorage()
  }, []); // empty array executes only on mount
```

about second argument tells `useEffect` dependencies when to run the code again. if you pass an empty array then executes only on mount. if you pass some variable like `[secureStorageAvailable]` then it will execute again when everytime `secureStorageAvailable` updates. Not passing a second argument you will face `useEffect` execute its code on every rerender.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it working with

```
  const [ secureStorageAvailable, setSecureStorageAvailable ] = React.useState<boolean|null>(null);
  React.useEffect( () => {
    (async () => {
      setSecureStorageAvailable(await SecureStore.isAvailableAsync());
    })();
  });
```

But it looks weird in that I have a function call inside an anonymous function call.  It works but I am not sure if it is right.

Comment: This is basically what you do if you want to use the async/await syntax instead of the promise syntax (`.then()`). Some people prefer to name their async function inside the useEffect and then call it directly afterwards i.e. `const checkAvailability = async () => {}; checkAvailability();`.

Comment: Your first attempt was to run `setSecureStorageAvailable` when the component is unmounted (during cleanup). Therefore it'd not have any effect to your current component. [Read more about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#recap)

Comment: Right, react hook callback functions are 100% synchronous, so you must create/invoke an asynchronous function from *within* the hook callback. What you have is a rather simple example, but @JacobSmit points out the common pattern.

Comment: Dan Abramov covers this in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326) from 2018. Probably also covers it in his blog, which has a lot of good info.